# Is $f(x + iy) = \exp(iy)$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

I know that if $|f| = c$ and $f$ is analytic in $D$ then $f = k$ in $D$.

If I take $f(z) = f(x + iy) = \exp(iy)$ then $|f| = 1$ in the complex plain.

But $f(z)$ is not constant, does this means that $f$ is not analytic? And if so why not?

Comment: your function, although smooth,  does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it is not analytic. If you write $f(x+yi)$ as $u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$, with $u(x,y),v(x,y)\in\Bbb R$, then $u(x,y)=\cos(y)$ and $v(x,y)=\sin(y)$. But then both $u_x$ and $v_x$ are the null function. On the other hand $u_y(x,y)=-\sin(y)$, and $v_y(x,y)=\cos(y)$. So, no point of $\Bbb R^2$ is a solution of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, and therefore $f$ is nowhere complex-differentable. Therefore, it is not holomorphic, and, in particular, it is not analytic.

Comment: $f$ is differentiable in the sense of $\mathbb{R}^2$, in fact is $C^\infty$-mooth. Just not analytic!

Comment: @OliverDiaz In the context of Complex Analysis, when a person states that a function is not differentiable the default option is that it is not differentiable in the complex sense. That's how I used the expression here.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: that maybe a little deceptive. Nowadays a complex differentiable function is called holomorphic (with some work that is the equivalent to analiticity). Making a clear distiction between differntiable (as a planar function) and complex differentiable is important. Other wise the following result seems redundant:  A  function $f$ that is differentiable at very point of a domain $D$ is holomorphic in $D$ (i.e. complex differentiable) if and only if $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: @JeanL. I have expanded my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: thanks to everyone!!!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Removing my downvote now... better late than never.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason: $|f(z)| = 1$ so $f$ is bounded.  Thus $f$ is not analytic by [Liouville's theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Liouville_theorems)